Help in solving PDE with charasteristic equation problem
It's my first time on this sort of problem, so I am having some trouble solving this PDE: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+e^{-x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac1y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$ and find function  $u(t,x,y)$ when $u(t=0, x,y)=y\ln(x)$
My work:
I write characteristic system of equations: $\frac{dt}{1} = \frac{dx}{e^{-x}} = \frac{dy}{\frac{1}{y}} = \frac{du}{0}$. From this we can see that $du=0 \implies u=c_1$. Then for second equation $\frac{dt}1=\frac{dx}{e^{-x}}\implies t=e^x+c_2$. From $\frac{dt}1=ydy\implies t=\frac12y^2+c_3$.
$u(t,x,y)=f(c_2,c_3)=f(t-e^x,t-\frac12y^2)$. Applying condition, I got $f(-e^x,-\frac12y^2)=y\ln x$?
I don't know what to do from this point on. Any help?

It follows from your partial solution that the general solution to the PDE is $$u(t,x,y)=f(c_2,c_3)=f(t-e^x,t-\frac{1}{2}y^2),$$where $f$ is an arbitrary differentiable function. Now use the condition $u(0,x,y)=y\ln(x)$ to determine $f$.

I am not sure how to apply it correctly, what do i do after i write $f(-e^x, -\frac{1}{2}y^2)=y\ln x$?

Let $\xi=-e^x$ and $\eta=-\frac{1}{2}y^2$; then $x=\ln(-\xi)$ and $y=\pm\sqrt{-2\eta}$, so
$$
f(-e^x,-\frac{1}{2}y^2)=y\ln x \implies f(\xi,\eta)=\pm\sqrt{-2\eta}\ln\ln(-\xi). \tag{1}
$$
Therefore,
$$
u(t,x,y)=f(t-e^x,t-\frac{1}{2}y^2)=\pm\sqrt{y^2-2t}\ln\ln(e^x-t). \tag{2}
$$

You can approach this problem by looking for a new system of coordinates, $X(t), Y(t)$ that are time-dependent, and a function $U(t,X,Y)$ such that
$$U(t,X(t),Y(t))=u(t,x,y)$$
Note that,
$$\frac{d U}{dt} = \frac{\partial U}{\partial t} + \frac{dX}{dt}\frac{\partial U}{\partial X} +  \frac{dY}{dt}\frac{\partial U}{\partial Y}$$
Therefore we can split the original PDE into a system of three ODEs,
$$\frac{d U}{dt} = 0,\qquad \frac{d X}{dt} = e^{-X}, \qquad \frac{d Y}{dt} = \frac{1}{Y}. $$
The latter two of these can be solved to find that,
$$X(0) = \ln(e^X-t), \qquad Y(0)=\pm\sqrt{Y^2-2t}$$
The other equation, $\dot U = 0$, with the initial condition gives us
$$U(t,X(t),Y(t)) = U(0,X(0),Y(0)) = Y(0) \ln(X(0))$$
From this we can conclude that the solution to your problem is given by
$$u(t,x,y) =\pm\sqrt{y^2 -2t}\ln(\ln(e^x-t))$$
